# SQLite & INNER JOIN Query

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update

Hi everyone I have this query where there are 3 tables in join. In Access it works, but in SQLite it gives me an error, how can I "adapt" the SQL command? thanks

```
UPDATE (
    CategoriaTB 
    INNER JOIN MagazzinoTB ON CategoriaTB.IDCategoria = 
MagazzinoTB.IDCategoria
) INNER JOIN PersoneTB ON MagazzinoTB.IDPersone = 
PersoneTB.IDPersone 
SET MagazzinoTB.DataReso = "aaa"
WHERE ((
    (PersoneTB.CodicePer)="F") 
    AND ((MagazzinoTB.Stato)=0) 
    AND ((MagazzinoTB.DataVendita) Is Null)
)
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run it in SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not support joins in the `UPDATE` statement, but you can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE MagazzinoTB 
SET DataReso = 'aaa'
WHERE Stato = 0 AND DataVendita IS NULL
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CategoriaTB c WHERE c.IDCategoria = MagazzinoTB.IDCategoria)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PersoneTB p WHERE p.IDPersone = MagazzinoTB.IDPersone AND p.CodicePer = 'F')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
UPDATE MagazzinoTB set DataReso = 'aaa' WHERE (IDCategoria, IDPersone)
IN (SELECT CategoriaTB.IDCategoria, PersoneTB.IDPersone FROM CategoriaTB 
INNER JOIN MagazzinoTB ON 
CategoriaTB.IDCategoria = MagazzinoTB.IDCategoria
INNER JOIN PersoneTB 
ON MagazzinoTB.IDPersone = PersoneTB.IDPersone
WHERE (((PersoneTB.CodicePer)="F") AND ((MagazzinoTB.Stato)=0) AND 
((MagazzinoTB.DataVendita) Is Null)));
```